# Test chat python p2p program cannot send messages properly

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I'm still new to Python, and I'm having an issue at a PoC p2p code that I was trying to write. It's a simple program to send messages between devices

The problem is that although it kinda of works, some devices cannot send messages, or detect new devices. My computer can send messages (I don't know about receiving, because I haven't been able to test it) and receives the message when other devices are discovered. The problem lies that when I try running it somewhere else (tried it in a VM, my laptop and even my phone) I cannot send messages at all. Between devices besides my computer nothing works at all. They both receive just fine, but cant send or get notified about other devices. Could it just be some network setting?

```
import socket
import threading
import random
import time

class Peer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.peer_id = str(random.randint(1000, 9999))
        self.peers = {}  # Store peer id and their address
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        self.sock.bind(('', 12345))
        self.sock.settimeout(1)  # Set a timeout on the socket
        self.running = True

    def start_broadcast(self):
        while self.running:
            self.sock.sendto(self.peer_id.encode(), ('<broadcast>', 12345))
            time.sleep(1)

    def listen_broadcast(self):
        while self.running:
            try:
                data, addr = self.sock.recvfrom(1024)
                message = data.decode()
                if message.isdigit() and len(message) == 4:  # Check if it's a peer ID
                    peer_id = message
                    if peer_id != self.peer_id and peer_id not in self.peers:
                        self.peers[peer_id] = addr
                        print(f'New peer discovered: {peer_id} at {addr}')
                else:
                    print(f'Received: {message}')
            except socket.timeout:
                pass  # Ignore timeout errors

    def send(self, peer_id, message):
        if peer_id in self.peers:
            self.sock.sendto(message.encode(), self.peers[peer_id])
        else:
            print('Peer not found')

def main():
    peer = Peer()
    print(f'Your peer ID is {peer.peer_id}')

    broadcast_thread = threading.Thread(target=peer.start_broadcast)
    broadcast_thread.start()

    listen_thread = threading.Thread(target=peer.listen_broadcast)
    listen_thread.start()

    while True:
        message = input('Enter message (format: peer_id message) or "exit" to quit: ')
        if message == 'exit':
            peer.running = False
            break
        elif ' ' in message:
            peer_id, message = message.split(' ', 1)
            peer.send(peer_id, message)

    # Wait for all threads to finish
    broadcast_thread.join()
    listen_thread.join()

    print('Exited')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I'm sorry if it's ugly, any feedback is welcome

I tried separating the sockets between broadcasting and receiving messages, but it still didn't worked out